# Stop dropping folders in dropzone

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone.js](https://www.dropzone.dev/js/) and I want to prevent dropping folders because it drops the folders recursively that may lead to a frozen page if there are thousands of files in nested folders.
How can I do that?

Let me explain in more detail. Here is how dropzone handles "drop" event:

```
{
key: "drop",
value: function drop(e) {
  if (!e.dataTransfer) {
    return;
  }

  this.emit("drop", e); // Convert the FileList to an Array
  // This is necessary for IE11

  var files = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
    files[i] = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
  } // Even if it's a folder, files.length will contain the folders.


  if (files.length) {
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;

    if (items && items.length && items[0].webkitGetAsEntry != null) {
      // The browser supports dropping of folders, so handle items instead of files
      this._addFilesFromItems(items);
    } else {
      this.handleFiles(files);
    }
  }

  this.emit("addedfiles", files);
}
```

I want to make a change to this to prevent dropping folders but I don't want to manipulate dropzone source code:

```
{
key: "drop",
value: function drop(e) {
  if (!e.dataTransfer) {
    return;
  }

  // ...

  if (files.length) {
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;

    if (items && items.length && items[0].webkitGetAsEntry != null) {
      // Here is the change
      var folder = items[0].webkitGetAsEntry().isDirectory;
      if (folder) {
        return;
      }
      this._addFilesFromItems(items);
    } else {
      this.handleFiles(files);
    }
  }

  this.emit("addedfiles", files);
}
```

So, how can I override "drop" event?

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.fullPath !== undefined && (file.fullPath.includes("/") || file.fullPath.includes("\\") )) {
        done("Please, do not upload a whole directory, only files that are inside.");
        return;
    }
    done();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the problem by removing dropzone's default "drop" event listener and adding my own listener.

BTW, I removed the event listener using [DOM removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) because dropzone adds the listeners with DOM addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the webkitdirectiory-attribute of the hidden file input to False. This will only allow (standalone) files to be uploaded.

```
$("div#dropzoneDiv").dropzone({
            url: '/upload',
            init: function() {
                this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("webkitdirectory", false);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to make this work with the documented `accept` function, but for those who still need it, I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

1. On the "addedfiles" event, filter out any file objects that don't have a type or have slashes in the path:

> ```
> dropzone.on("addedfiles", (fileList) => {
>   fileList = Object.entries(fileList)
>     .map((f) => f[1])
>     .filter(
>       (f) =>
>         f.type &&
>         !f.fullPath?.includes("/") &&
>         !f.fullPath?.includes("\\"),
>     );
>   if (fileList.length == 0) return;
>
>   // enqueue files
> }
> ```

2. On the "addedfile" event, prevent creation of the file by removing the file from the dropzone instance, using a similar check:

> ```
> dropzone.on("addedfile", (file) => {
>   if (
>     !file.type ||
>     file.fullPath?.includes("/") ||
>     file.fullPath?.includes("\\")
>   ) {
>     this.removeFile(file);
>     return;
>   }
>
>   // custom handling
> }
> ```

Depending on your auto enqueue/auto process configuration, you may have to do either both or one of these steps, but you cannot avoid consuming these events at all.